# how i can set sytle for print html page in css

Tags: html, css

i write this code to print html page in paper copy using paper 80mm but this code not working correctly i need to a few help to correct it

```
@media print {
    div.invoice{
       background: #FFFFFF;
       width:40%;
       margin-left:30%;
       margin-top: 0px
       }
       div.invoice div{
          background: #FFFFFF;
          color: black;
          margin-left: 1%;
       }
       div.invoice h2{
            font-size: 14px;
       }
       div.invoice h3{
            font-size: 13px;
       }
       div.invoice h4{
            font-size: 12px;
       }
       div.invoice div h2, div.invoice div h3, div.invoice div h4{
       color: black;
       line-height:0.8em;
       margin-top:1px;
       -webkit-margin-before: 0.8em;
       -webkit-margin-after: 0.8em;
          }
      h1, h2, h3, h4{
          -webkit-margin-before: 0.4em;
          -webkit-margin-after: 0.4em;
          }
   }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Please be more detailed.

Comment: when i press print button that displayed as screen style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

Step 1 : Add **media="print"** to your stylesheet link or example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="print" >
```

step 2 : Then follow below media query.

```
@media print 
{
 body { margin: 0; background-image: none; font-size: 12pt; }
}
```

Comment: link tag you upload between head tag and @media print add in your CSS file